# Conditions on a set implying properties on neighborhoods

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in a Euclidean space, and for $\epsilon>0$, let $V_\varepsilon$ be the  $\varepsilon-$neighborhood  of $F$ i.e. the set of points $x$ having a distance less than $\varepsilon$ from $F$. Consider the following condition on $F$:

A) There is $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0$, the complement of $V_\epsilon$ is connected.

Are there some topological conditions applied to $F$ that imply condition A? By topological condition I mean for example that $F$ is contractible, or...?

Comment: A remark on $V_\epsilon$: in general, they do not form a basis of open neighborhoods of $F$ unless, say, $F$ is compact. Under some conditions, Alexander duality should give some information.

Comment: Simple remark: contractibility is not enough, as $S^1$ with a point removed shows